# Parentheses in C, how?

Tags: c, mathematical-expressions

I want to write this equation in C but I don't know how to use the right parentheses.

```
Eq=sqrt(e^(-((T-thr))/T) )   + (1-a)/4
```

Comment: If I've interpreted your formula correctly `eq = sqrt(exp(-1 * (T - thr) / T)) + ((1 - a) / 4)` ought to do it. But I'm not sure - it might be `eq = (sqrt(exp(-1 * (T - thr) / T)) + (1 - a)) / 4`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `/ 4` term - are you trying to divide the entire preceding expression by four, or just the `(1 - a)`? What the heck, it's only software - try 'em both and see what you like better - unless you're building something like a nuclear reactor control system, in which case you might want to review this carefully before implementing anything. Best of luck.

Comment: What exactly does "I don't know how to use the right parenthesis" mean?

Comment: @BobJarvis: Why do you replace the unary `-` with a multiplication by `-1`?

Comment: I believe OP meant "...how to use parentheses correctly". YMMV.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I like it better. YMMV.

Comment: I thought that by "right parentheses" you mean the `)` character. Did you really mean "how to use parentheses correctly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the `^` operator is not exponentiation. Instead, in C, we write e<sup>x</sup> as `exp(x)`. Other than that, your equation is the same in C. I would put spaces around some of the operators, though:

```
Eq = sqrt(exp(-(T - thr) / T)) + (1 - a) / 4;
```

I have assumed that your variables (`T`, `thr`, and `a`) are a floating-point type (`float` or `double`). If they are integers, you probably want to force the compiler to use floating-point arithmetic, which you can do (for example) like this:

```
Eq = sqrt(exp(-((double)T - thr) / T)) + (1 - a) / 4.0;
```

Also... `-(T - thr)` is the same as `(thr - T)`, so we can simplify:

```
Eq = sqrt(exp((thr - (double)T) / T)) + (1 - a) / 4.0;
```

And (a<sup>b</sup>)<sup>c</sup> = a<sup>b c</sup>,  which we can apply to the square root of the exponential: √(e<sup>x</sup>) = (e<sup>x</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup> = e<sup>x/2</sup>. So we can eliminate the square root:

```
Eq = exp((thr - (double)T) / (2 * T))) + (1 - a) / 4.0;
```